# Find out with which column the value of another column matches

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I've the following query:

```
SELECT g.group_player1_user_id, g.group_player2_user_id, g.group_player3_user_id, g.group_player4_user_id, r.runk_user_id
FROM groups g
JOIN runks r
ON g.group_id = r.runk_group_id
```

This will give the following output:

[image]

I need to know if my 'runk' is belonging to player 1, 2, 3 or 4. 
How do I find out what column matches my runk_user_id?

*(I am aware not all user_ids will match but that's because I've been playing around with my data. This will not happen in the production version)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to test all them. You can accomplish this in a fairly elegant way with a `case` expression:

```
SELECT r.runk_user_id,
       CASE r.runk_user_id WHEN g.group_player1_user_id THEN 'player 1'
                           WHEN g.group_player2_user_id THEN 'player 2'
                           WHEN g.group_player3_user_id THEN 'player 3'
                           WHEN g.group_player4_user_id THEN 'player 4'
                           ELSE 'no player matches'
       END AS player
FROM   groups g
JOIN   runks r ON g.group_id = r.runk_group_id
```